# Retrieve elements in js from a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Im trying to get stock prices from this api: https://english.api.rakuten.net/apidojo/api/yahoo-finance1?endpoint=apiendpoint_a1e0ecc6-0a3a-43fd-8133-77a66d33f68c

In the web page you can see the json objects that getting historical data returns, even though Im using their fetch code to call the api, response is empty {}.

Does anyone know how to get the adjclose variable and store it in an array?

This is my code so far

```
    let symbol = "DIS";
    let unixTimeStamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000).toString();
    let url = "https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/stock/v2/get-historical-data?frequency=1d&filter=history&period1=1&period2=" + unixTimeStamp + "&symbol=" + symbol;
    fetch(url, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
             "x-rapidapi-host": "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
              "x-rapidapi-key": "Secret api key"
           }
    })
    .then(response => {

        console.log(response);

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Show us what you have now (I mean JS code, maybe HTML)

Comment: @Anton code added - no html.

Comment: You can access this data without an API key, going directly to Yahoo Finance:  "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/DIS?interval=1d&period1=1&period2=" + unixTimestamp.  Or, if you're just trying to get all of the data for a specific symbol:  "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/DIS?interval=1d&range=max"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MDN documentation,

> "This is just an HTTP response, not the actual JSON. To extract the
> JSON body content from the response, we use the json()".

In your case, you need to call json() on your response to parse through it and then you can do something with that data.

```
 fetch(url, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
             "x-rapidapi-host": "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
              "x-rapidapi-key": "Secret api key"
           }
    })
    .then(response => {
        response.json();
        console.log(response.json())
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

See Fetch docs: [MDN Fetch Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)